# Android 4.3 jelly Bean Time format issue

Tags: java, android

My date format is  this "yyyy-MM-dd"  and when i get month using this function it return me wrong format of month. For example instead of "July" it return me  only "J"

here is the function:

```
public static String getMonthName(String date) {

    Date mDate = Utils.parseDate(date);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM");
    String time = sdf.format(mDate);
    return time;

}
```

andy idea what to do?

Edit:
and here is my `parseDate(String date)` function

```
public static Date parseDate(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            return formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new Date();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What culture are you using?

Comment: **Never** rely on default encoding and default locale. **Never.** When parsing date (or even floating point numbers, as the decimal might be different), you should **always** explicitly specify the proper format.

Comment: i am using default locale

Comment: @Ali then most likely this contributes to the problem.

Comment: So what patch i need in this function?

Comment: This problem has occured after i updated my Nexus 7 to 4.3 OS

Comment: @JonSkeet the bug is resolved and i found a problem in Oracle docs for 'SimpledateFormat' class here you can see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have one M to much

M:1 
MM:01 
MMM:Jan 
MMMM:January 
MMMMM:J

Comment: Yes this was the issue. ;) but here the doc for simpledateformat, and you can see there are five 'M' there :_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Yeah but: M:1.....MMMMM:J in Android documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Five-count patterns (such as "MMMMM") used for the shortest non-numeric representation of a field were introduced in Jelly Bean MR2 (API level 18).